# registrar números decimales de c# a sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

HOLA BUEN DÍA TENGO EN C# UN PEQUEÑO PROYECTO QUE ESTOY HACIENDO EN CAPAS PERO ESTOY CON EL PROBLEMA DE LOS DECIMALES ESTA ES MI CLASE DProducto EN LA CAPA DATOS CON ESTA VARIABLE Y EL SGTE METODO:

```
private decimal _PrecioProducto;

public string RegistrarProducto(DProducto dProducto) {

        string respuesta;
        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = Conexion.conexion;
            mySqlConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            mySqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection;
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "registrarProducto";
            mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parPrecio = new SqlParameter();
            parPrecio.ParameterName = "@precioProducto";
            parPrecio.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
            parPrecio.Precision = 9;
            parPrecio.Scale = 2;
            parPrecio.Value = dProducto.PrecioProducto;
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parPrecio);

            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            respuesta = "Exito";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            respuesta = "Error al registrar Producto " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mySqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

EN LA CAPA NEGOCIO TENGO ESTE METODO:

```
public static string registrarProducto(decimal precioProducto) {
        DProducto dProducto = new DProducto();
        dProducto.PrecioProducto = precioProducto;

        return dProducto.RegistrarProducto(dProducto);
    }
```

AHORA EN PRESENTACION TENGO LO SGTE:

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            string respuesta = 
                NProducto.registrarProducto(
                   Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtPrecio.Text));
            if (respuesta == "Exito")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Producto registrado", "Sistema de Ventas", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

EN SQL MI TABLA PRODUCTO CON SU PROC. ALMACENADO:

```
create table producto(
codigoProducto int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
precioProducto decimal(9,2) not null
)

create procedure registrarProducto
@precioProducto decimal(9,2)
as
insert into producto(precioProducto) values(@precioProducto);
go
```

AL EJECUTAR EL PROYECTO INGRESO UN NUMERO DECIMAL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PERO EN LA BD SE REGISTRA REDONDEADO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ME PODRIAN BRINDAR UNA AYUDITA CON ESTE PROBLEMA PORFAVOR :D

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna de decimal a float?

Comment: Estás utilizando el tipo de dato "money" en SQL Server?

Comment: De igual manera cambiando a float sigue pasando lo mismo lo redondea y si ven en sql server lo tengo como decimal

Comment: Si ejecutas el sp directo en la base de datos de igual manera te lo redondea ?

Comment: E ejecutado el sp desde la bd y no lo redondea puse el mismo numero de la imagen 27.57 y lo registro tal y como esta. Entonces donde estaría el problema?

Comment: El problema está en alguna parte de tu código de C#. En especial, revisa los valores de `parPrecio.Value` y `dProducto.PrecioProducto`.

Comment: Revisando paso a paso la ejecución del proyecto veo que el número decimal (27.57) pasa tal y como esta tanto por la capa de datos negocio y presentación ya cuando reviso en la bd sql server veo que aparece redondeado. no se cual es el problema